# I want to make tabs in WordPress custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, admin

I want to create tabs for custom plugin it shows me tab but input field which i have given it in the function it does't show these fields when i inspect it it shows hidden fields which would be showed default in it.

And i want to add a big form on the second tab suggest me also how would i do that.

Here is my code :

```
<?php 

function review_shortcode() {
?>
 <div class="wrap">
        <h1> Review</h1>

        <?php
            $active_tab = "api-setting";
            if(isset($_GET["tab"]))
            {
                if($_GET["tab"] == "api-setting")
                {
                    $active_tab = "api-setting";
                }
                else
                {
                    $active_tab = "create-shortcode";
                }
            }
        ?>

        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="?page=review&tab=api-setting" class="nav-tab <?php if($active_tab == 'api-setting'){echo 'nav-tab-active';} ?> "><?php _e('Api Settings'); ?></a>
            <a href="?page=review&tab=create-shortcode" class="nav-tab <?php if($active_tab == 'create-shortcode'){echo 'nav-tab-active';} ?>"><?php _e('Shortcode Generator'); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php

                settings_fields("api_validation");

                do_settings_sections("review");

                submit_button(); 

            ?>          
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
function display_options()
{
    add_settings_section("api_validation", "API Settings", "display_header_options_content", "review");

    if(isset($_GET["tab"]))
    {
        if($_GET["tab"] == "api-setting")
        {
            add_settings_field("api_sett", "API", "display_logo_form_element", "review", "api_validation");
            register_setting("api_validation", "api_sett");
        }
        else
        {
            add_settings_field("advertising_code", "Ads Code", "display_ads_form_element", "review", "api_validation");      

            register_setting("api_validation", "advertising_code");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        add_settings_field("api_sett", "API", "display_logo_form_element", "review", "api_validation");
        register_setting("api_validation", "api_sett");
    }

}

function display_header_options_content(){echo "check review working";}
function display_logo_form_element()
{
    ?>
        <input type="text" name="api_sett" id="api_sett" value="<?php echo get_option('api_sett'); ?>" />
    <?php
}
function display_ads_form_element()
{
    ?>
        <input type="text" name="advertising_code" id="advertising_code" value="<?php echo get_option('advertising_code'); ?>" />
    <?php
}

add_action("admin_init", "display_options");
}
```

Comment: can you post your full code? i getting error. and where you use the shortcode?

Comment: I figure it out i will put function with in function
when i put display option function  separately and it will work.

Comment: Now I have an another issue how would i check data on first tab but on my second tab where i will create short code but on copy button it will refresh the page and that button would be gone so how would i stop refreshing the page.

Comment: your code is not working for me. can you post your updated code and explain the issue?